# Error while installing Flutter in Linux

Tags: flutter

I set the path variable and echo the path and it give me expected output

```
uttu@Lore-UK:~/flutter$ export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:$PATH
uttu@Lore-UK:~/flutter$ echo $PATH
/home/uttu/flutter/flutter/bin:/home/uttu/home/flutter/bin:/home/uttu/flutter/flutter/bin:/home/uttu/home/flutter/bin:/home/uttu/.local/share/umake/bin:/home/uttu/bin:/home/uttu/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

but when I ran flutter doctor it show

```
$ flutter doctor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 4, in <module>
    from _gdbm import *
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 7, in <module>
    import dbm.gnu as gdbm
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/dbm/gnu.py", line 6, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-gdbm package')
ImportError: No module named '_gdbm', please install the python3-gdbm package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 27, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.util import crash_guard
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gdbm
ImportError: No module named 'gdbm'
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error and how to solve it

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your error message you are missing the module 'gdbm' as it says here:

> please install the python3-gdbm package

Try installing this module and running flutter doctor again.
Other people have had the same problem [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/720416/no-module-named-gdbm)